# Curvy tabs in Eclipse RCP App

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-3.6

I am currently using Eclipse Helios Service Release 1.  I am new to both the IDE and the platform.

My question is, how do I get the same curvy tab on my app that of the IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/413931/?srch=curvy%20tab#msg_413931) and this [blog post](http://vyshemirsky.blogspot.com/2007/10/curvy-tabs-in-your-eclipse-rcp.html):

See "[eclipse look&feel customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978014/eclipse-lookfeel-customization)" for more.

All see this "[java-tips](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-change-the-shape-of-the-title-of-the-view.html)":

[image: curvy tabs on Eclipse RCP]

> To change the shape of the title of a view following line of code can be written in the `preWindowOpen()` method of the `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor`.

```
PlatformUI.getPreferenceStore().setValue(IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants.SHOW_TRADITIONAL_STYLE_TABS, false);
```

Note that there might be an issue with long titles when there is many tabs:
See [bug 322623](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=322623):
"Editor tabs do not show ellipsis for long filenames when using new style tabs."